# How to vertically align div next to padded div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that contains two children, each of which is framed using bootstrap's columns. However, within these divs, what I need to be able to do is that for the left div, I have some icons that need to vertically aligned and centered relative to the div to the right.

The div to the right contains an anchor tag that acts as a button, and has some padding. This causes the button to extend downwards, and the left div doesn't occupy the remaining height.

I have attached here a
[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJxPOV)
to show what I am talking about.

```css
.shareContainer {
  padding: 28px 0px;
}

.row {
  background: #eee !important;
}

.fa-icon {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  color: #ff7350;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 18px 50px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Lato";
  border-radius: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #fff !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fb8669;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

.arrowRight {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:hover {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container shareContainer'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <i class='fa fa-share-square-o fa-icon'></i>
      <i class='fa fa-facebook-square fa-icon'></i>
      <i class='fa fa-twitter fa-icon'></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a target="_blank" class='button' }>
              register for event <svg class='arrowRight'width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="arrow-right"><path d="M9 4l7 8-7 8" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
            </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) to vertically align elements:

```
.shareIcons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Codepen demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeZVoa**

Comment: this helped the most. im not on bootstrap 4 (put it in codepen by accident), im on 3, and this was the simplest explanation of how to get it working. i need to learn flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need to apply these built-in Bootstrap 4 classes to the LHS div with the icons

```
d-flex 
justify-content-center 
align-items-center
```

So, now the `shareContainer` div will look like this:

```
<div class="container shareContainer">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"> <=====
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            ...
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMWopY)

What it does basically is apply these CSS properties:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a `margin:auto;` to the surrounding container:

```
.share {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Demo: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kr2cq8d9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for your centering

```css
.shareContainer {
  padding: 28px 0px;
}

.row {
  background: #eee !important;
}

.fa-icon {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  color: #ff7350;
}

.flex {
  display: flex; /* new */
  align-items: center; /* new */
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 18px 50px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Lato";
  border-radius: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #fff !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fb8669;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

.arrowRight {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:hover {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right-button {
  margin-left: auto; /* new */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container shareContainer'>
  <div class="flex">
      <i class='fa fa-share-square-o fa-icon'></i>
      <i class='fa fa-facebook-square fa-icon'></i>
      <i class='fa fa-twitter fa-icon'></i>
      <a target="_blank" class='button right-button' }>
              register for event <svg class='arrowRight'width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="arrow-right"><path d="M9 4l7 8-7 8" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
            </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```